# we need to find $m+n$.

Tags: arithmetic

I just dont understand this question, could any one tell me how to solve this one?

A pen costs   $13$ dollar and a notebook costs $35$ dollar, let $m$ be the maximum number of items that can be bought for $1000$ dollars and $n$ be the minimum number of items that can be bought for the same amount. we need to find $m+n$.

a) 76

b) 88

c) 96

d) 98

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: if you buy only notebooks (the most expensive), you will have the minimum number of items.

Comment: Try dividing the total dollars by the cost of each.

Comment: Are we allowed to not use all the money?  If so, then the minimum number of items is $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question here is vague so I'll offer a few solutions.

Option 1: You don't have to spend all the money.

Trivial solution for minimum keep all the money and buy nothing $n = 0$ 
Trivial solution for maximum only buy pens $m = 76$
$m+n = 76$

Option 2: You don't have to spend all the money but must buy if you can afford it.

Buy as many books as you can  $28$ you have 20 dollars change so can buy one pen $n=29$
Trivial solution for maximum only buy pens $m = 76$
$m+n = 105$

Option 3: you must spend exactly 1000 dollars

Now we are looking for solutions to $13 \cdot x + 35 \cdot y = 1000$
We know that number of books must be less than  28 and not less than zero we can try them all.

Possible solutions are:
 
10 books and 50 pens $m = 60$ 
23 books and 15 pens $n = 38$
$m+n = 98$

Any other numbers of books and you are left with change.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of pens to be bought; let $y$ be the number of notebooks to be bought.  Thus, it is implied that $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers.  $m$ is the maximum value of $x+y$ (and $n$ is the minimum value of $x+y$).  If we are allowed to spend less than 1000 dollars, then $x$ and $y$ must be chosen so that $13x+35y\le 1000$.  If it is required to spend exactly 1000 dollars, then the condition is $13x+35y=1000$.

Comment: what is the answer and how to solve it?

Comment: The question is vague.  Must we spend all the 1000 dollars?

Comment: If we must spend exactly 1000 dollars, there is only a limited set of values of $x$ and $y$.  For example, one possibility is $x=50,y=10$.